# Random compilation errors at Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, random, compiler-errors

I was developing an ASP.NET project and all went OK.

But now I'm getting errors, BUT everything in the code is OK.

I press F6 to compile all the solution, and I got errors everywhere. But the code is all OK (keep reading, you'll understand). Then I try to compile it again,again, again, again..... And in a tottaly random moment, i got sucess.

Then I try to view the page in browser. Compiling error! 
Compile it again, Success.
Refresh the page, Compiling error! 
Refresh the page again, Success!

And I didn't changed ANYTHING in the code.

And then I can keep programming normally, but when I close VS and open it again, this problem comes again.

Other things I try: deleting the bin folder and compiling again, rebuild the solution, build each project individually....nothing works.

Visual Studio is compiling "when he wants".

Why the hell this is happening?

Comment: You won't be getting much help unless you post the errors...

Comment: Don't use Build (F6), go for rebuild. It will refresh the references.

Comment: There is 1 error: Error 1 'Mensagem' does not contain a definition for 'men_vtitulo' and no extension method 'men_vtitulo' accepting a first argument of type 'Mensagem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Site\MsgMarketing\Wizard.aspx.cs 73 17 D:\...\Site\

Comment: The other 65 errors are just the same. If I try to compile again and again, randomly it will work fine. I tried to use Rebuild, but the same thing occours.

Comment: Basically it cant find the classes and references, but when I try to code the same thing, Intellisense can get the classes just as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I created a Handler with the same name, "Mensagem", and sometimes the compiler tried to compile the handler first, and sometimes, the Mensagem class first.

I just changed the Handler name, and its OK now.

That's incredible how these small errors can cause a great pain in the head.

Another thing I observed, i have a lot of classes, but only one class is returning false erros.

The main error is:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'Entidades.Mensagem' to 'Mensagem'"

The class "Mensagem" is in the namespace "Entidades", that is referenced in the "using" section. When i try to code it, everything went OK, but when compiling, i got erros.

Its just this class.